# jQuery UI .detach().appendTo() DOM not updated right away within drag and drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Here is a code example using jquery ui drag and drop:  http://jsfiddle.net/kwMpH/7/

The button "Show Approval Levels" tries to show which user bubbles fall into which boxes.  It seems to work but there is a scenario where I can break it:

1. drag one element to the first approval level.
2. click "Add Approval Level"
3. take a different element and add it to the newly created
       approval level
4. move the bubble from level 2 to level 1 then QUICKLY click the "Show Approval Levels"

It is worth noting that the reason I'm using the detach and appendTo is the same "form submission" requirements of this older post:

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="topInstructions">Drag and Drop a one or more categories of users to one or more approval levels.</div>
    <div class="workFlowNameArea">
        <div class="workFlowNameSubArea">
            <div style="font-weight:bold;">Work Flow Name</div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="workFlowName" id="workFlowName" maxlength="100" width="50" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="workFlowNameSubArea" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 17px;">
            <input id="saveButton" type="button" value="Save" />
        </div>
        <div class="workFlowNameSubArea" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 17px;">
            <input id="addApprovalLevel" type="button" value="Add Approval Level" />
        </div>
        <div class="workFlowNameSubArea" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 17px;">
            <input id="showState" type="button" value="Show State" />
        </div>
        <div class="workFlowNameSubArea" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 17px;">
            <input id="appLevel" type="button" value="Show approval Levels" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropGroup">
        <div id="approval1" class="approvalText">Approval Level 1
            <div id="deleteApproval1" class="deleteApproval" style="visibility: hidden;">
                <img src="/images/redX.gif" />
            </div>
            <div id="droppable1" class="droppable"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="arrow1" class="arrow">
            <img src="/images/arrow_in_circle_down.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="ellipsis1" class="ellipsis">
            <img src="/images/ellipsis.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="choices">
        <div class="approvalText">Categories</div>
        <div class="draggable" title="click and drag to an approval level" style="background: #CC0000; color: #fff;">System Administrators</div>
        <div class="draggable" title="click and drag to an approval level" style="background: #FF9933; color: #000;">Administrators</div>
        <div class="draggable" title="click and drag to an approval level" style="background: #FFFF00; color: #000;">Managers</div>
        <div class="draggable" title="click and drag to an approval level" style="background: #99FF66; color: #000;">Instructors</div>
        <div class="draggable" title="click and drag to an approval level" style="background: #66CCFF; color: #000;">School Administrators</div>
        <div class="draggable" title="click and drag to an approval level" style="background: #6600FF; color: #fff;">Users</div>
        <div class="clonable" title="click to create a custom group" style="background: #999; color: #fff;">Custom</div>
    </div>
</div>
.draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.clonable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.droppable {
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-color: #999;
    color: #999;
    border-style: dashed;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.topInstructions {
    position: relative;
    float: top;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.dropGroup {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.choices {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 430px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.approvalText {
    color: #999;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.deleteApproval {
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.workFlowNameArea {
    position: relative;
    float: top;
    width: 680px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.workFlowNameSubArea {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.container {
    width: 680px;
    position: relative;
}
var globalElement;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".draggable").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        revert: true,
        containment: "document",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            globalElement = $(this);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            globalElement = null;
        }
    });

    $(".droppable").droppable({
        accepts: ".draggable",
        tolerance: "intersect",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            dropFunction($(this), event, ui);
        }
    }).hover(function () {
        if ($(this).find(".draggable").length < 1) {

        }
    });

    $(".choices").droppable({
        accepts: ".draggable",
        tolerance: "intersect",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            dropFunction($(this), event, ui);
        }
    });

    $(".clonable").click(function () {
        //TODO pop up for user list
    });
    $(".startOverButton").click(function () {
        // is this possible?
    });
    $("#addApprovalLevel").click(function () {
        addNextApprovalLevel();
    });
    $("#saveButton").click(function () {
        saveWorkflow();
        console.log("approval levels\n");
        $(".droppable").each(function (index) {
            console.log((index + 1) + ":" + $(this).find(".draggable").length + ":" + $(this).find(".draggable").text());
        });
    });
    $("#showState").click(function () {
        alert(state);
    });
    $("#appLevel").click(function () {
        // this does not work in drop function but does work here... maybe because drop is not completely done?
        //console.log("approval levels");
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){}
        var str = "approval levels";
        $(".droppable").each(function (index) {
            str += "" + (index + 1) + ":" + $(this).find(".draggable").length + ":" + $(this).find(".draggable").text() + "\n";
        });
        alert(str);

    });

});

var state = new Array();


function dropFunction(jObj, event, ui) {

    if (globalElement != null) {
        ui.helper.fadeOut();
        globalElement.detach().appendTo(jObj);
        $(jObj).css("border-color", "#999");

        drpGroup = $(".dropGroup").height();
        net = 0;
        $.each($(".droppable"), function (i, drp) {
            oldHeight = $(drp).height();
            newHeight = ($(drp).find(".draggable").length * 45) + 75;
            $(drp).css("height", newHeight);
            net += newHeight - oldHeight;
            //console.log("old = " + oldHeight + ", new = " + newHeight + ", net = " + net);
        });
        drpGroup += net;
        $(".dropGroup").css("height", drpGroup);
        //console.log("new drop group height = " + $(".dropGroup").height());
    } else {
        //console.log("too fast!");
    }
}

function addNextApprovalLevel() {
    var curHighest = $(".droppable").length;
    $("#ellipsis" + curHighest).remove();
    var nextLevelNum = curHighest + 1;
    var newApprovalText = "<div id='approval" + nextLevelNum + "'>Approval Level " + nextLevelNum + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id='deleteApproval" + nextLevelNum + "' class='deleteApproval'><img src='/images/redX.gif' /></div>" + "</div>";

    var newApprovalBox = $("<div id='droppable" + nextLevelNum + "' class='droppable'>" + "</div>");
    //$("#droppable" + curHighest).clone().attr("id", "droppable" + nextLevelNum);


    $(newApprovalBox).droppable({
        accepts: ".draggable",
        tolerance: "intersect",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            dropFunction($(this), event, ui);
            //$("#droppable1").css("height", $("#droppable1").find(".draggable").length * 75);
            //console.log($("#droppable1").find(".draggable").length + "\n" +
            //      $("#droppable1").find(".draggable").text() );
        }
    });
    $("#arrow" + curHighest).css("margin-bottom", "5px");
    $(".dropGroup").append(newApprovalText);
    $(".dropGroup").append(newApprovalBox);
    var newArrow = "<div id='arrow" + nextLevelNum + "' class='arrow'><img src='/images/arrow_in_circle_down.png' /></div>";
    var newEllipsis = "<div id='ellipsis" + nextLevelNum + "' class='ellipsis'><img src='/images/ellipsis.png' /></div>";
    $(".dropGroup").append(newArrow);
    $(".dropGroup").append(newEllipsis);
    $(".dropGroup").css("height", $(".dropGroup").height() + 170);

    $("#deleteApproval" + nextLevelNum).click(function () {
        if ($("#droppable" + nextLevelNum).parent().find(".draggable").length >= 1) {
            alert("A user category must first be removed before an approval level can be deleted.");
        } else {
            deleteApprovalBox($(this));
        }
    });
}

function deleteApprovalBox(jqAppBox) {
    level = parseInt($(jqAppBox).attr("id").substring("deleteApproval".length));
    $("#approval" + level).remove();
    $("#droppable" + level).remove();
    $("#arrow" + level).remove();
    level++;
    while ($("#approval" + level).length) {
        $("#approval" + level).html("Approval Level " + (level - 1) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id='deleteApproval" + (level - 1) + "' class='deleteApproval'><img src='/images/redX.gif' /></div>");
        $("#approval" + level).attr("id", "approval" + (level - 1));
        $("#droppable" + level).attr("id", "droppable" + (level - 1));
        $("#arrow" + level).attr("id", "arrow" + (level - 1));

        $("#deleteApproval" + (level - 1)).click(function () {
            if ($("#droppable" + (level - 1)).parent().find(".draggable").length >= 1) {
                alert("A user category must first be removed before an approval level can be deleted.");
            } else {
                deleteApprovalBox($(this));
            }
        });
        level++;
    }
    level--;
    if ($("#ellipsis" + level).length == 1) {
        $("#ellipsis" + level).attr("id", "ellipsis" + (level - 1));
    }
}

function saveWorkflow() {


    // validate the name    
    var alphaNum = new RegExp(/^([\sa-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$/);
    if ($("#workFlowName").val().length < 1) {
        alert("Work flow name must be between 1 and 100 characters.");
        return false;
    }
    if (!alphaNum.test($("#workFlowName").val())) {
        alert("Invalid Work flow name.  Must have numbers or letters.");
        return false;
    }

    // check if there are no empty

    // check if any approval levels are empty
    if ($(".droppable").length > 1) {
        $.each($(".droppable"), function (i, drp) {
            //console.log(i + ":" + $(drp).find(".draggable").length);
            if ($(drp).find(".draggable").length < 1) {
                $(drp).css("border-color", "red");
                alert("Approval Level " + (i + 1) + " is empty.  Delete?");
                // TODO, implement an approval level delete method hooked into the NO of the YES/NO             
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    //var findResult = $("#droppable1").find(".draggable");

    // remove ellipis... do we need to do this?
    //var curHighest = $(".droppable").length;
    //$("#ellipsis" + curHighest).remove();
}
```

Comment: The clone and the original are both being counted while the clone is still fading out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `helper: clone` and fading the helper out once dropped.  While this fade is in progress, the helper is being counted (in the original box) as well as the original element (which is counted in the new box).  This is leading to the dragged element being counted in both boxes.  You need to either remove the helper from the container or somehow not count it.  One option would be to add a class to the helper to distinguish it from a real element.  Something like this:

In start:

```
ui.helper.addClass("ui-helper");
```

In count code:

```
$(this).find(".draggable").not(".ui-helper").length
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwMpH/10/

Comment: jquery UI itself adds a class to the helper which is `ui-draggable-dragging` which could be used instead, but I would probably tend to stick to my own class that I handle myself.